# Stripping out illegal characters such as question marks "????" from names of my files on Windows 7

Tags: command-line, file-management, rename, filenames

I need a simple free software program that can strip out illegal characters such as question marks `????` from names of my files on Windows 7, 64 bit and can strip them in batch/bulk

Comment: If you have a lot filenames with "?" characters in them, then you should probably look for the cause of these filenames too, and not just stripping away these characters.

Comment: Sometimes Windows will "truncate" the file names due to its size. NTFS partitions limit the filename to 255 characters (someone please correct me if i am wrong)

Comment: 255 is correct.

Comment: Bulk File Rename can do it...http://www.bulkrenameutility.co.uk/Main_Intro.php

Comment: @Moab, that sounds like an answer to me...

Answer (score 0):

Bulk File Rename can do it.

http://www.bulkrenameutility.co.uk/Main_Intro.php